# Plot The Magnetization

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, matrix, numerical-integration, physics

I have a problem with plotting a function M(T).
The matrix is the following:

```
 h[k_]={{368 + 68*(2.2 - Cos[k/2]^2),-368., 0., 0.},{-368.,368 + 736*Cos[k/2] + 68*(2.2 - Cos[k/2]^2),-368., 0.}, {0., -368.,368 + 736*Cos[k/2] + 68*(2.2 - Cos[k/2]^2), -368.},{0., 0., -368., 368 + 68*(2.2 - Cos[k/2]^2)}};
```

[image]

The function I wanna plot is :

```
  s=1;n=4;
 
Plot[1-1/(n*s)*1/(2*Pi)^2*\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(Pi\)]\(\((\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(Pi\)]\*FractionBox[\(1\), \(Exp[\*FractionBox[\(Tr[Eigenvalues[h[k]]]\), \(t\)]] - 1\)] \[DifferentialD]k)\)\[DifferentialD]k\)\),{t,0,1000}]
```

[image]

[image]

Note that k is from zero to Pi, k=kx=ky. betta is 1/T

The curve should look like this :

[image]

Comment: What happens when you try to run your code? Do you get errors? Warnings? Do you get a plot that's different from your expectation?

Comment: Please note, that function `Tr[Eigenvalues[h[k]]]` is periodic with a period of `4 Pi`.  Are integral limits `{k,0,Pi}` or `{k,0,4Pi}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function `g[k_] := Tr[Eigenvalues[h[k]]]` is periodic with a period of `4 Pi`, therefore we suppose that integral should be defined as follows

```
h[k_] = {{368 + 68*(2.2 - Cos[k/2]^2), -368., 0., 0.}, {-368., 
    368 + 736*Cos[k/2] + 68*(2.2 - Cos[k/2]^2), -368., 
    0.}, {0., -368., 
    368 + 736*Cos[k/2] + 68*(2.2 - Cos[k/2]^2), -368.}, {0., 
    0., -368., 368 + 68*(2.2 - Cos[k/2]^2)}};
g[k_] := Tr[Eigenvalues[h[k]]];

f[t_?NumericQ] := 
  4 Pi NIntegrate[1/(Exp[g[k]/t] - 1), {k, 0, 4 Pi}, 
    AccuracyGoal -> 2, PrecisionGoal -> 2];
```

Visualization

```
s = 1; n = 4; Plot[1 - 1/(s n) 1/(2*Pi)^2*f[t], {t, .1, 1600}, 
 Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 FrameLabel -> {"T(K)", "<\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(S\), \(z\)]\)>"}]
```

[image: Figure 1]